# How to extract multiple tables with command line in Tabula?

Tags: java, extract, tabula

In tabula web-interface, you can choose more then one table with different coordinates, is that possible with direct command?

Answer (score 0):

Not without making changes to the code. Check the [code in the repo](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/blob/master/src/main/java/technology/tabula/CommandLineApp.java#L207).

An awful hack is to execute tabula for each area you want to extract.